# Extracting point data / WMS out of (browser) geoviewer

Tags: wms, point, wfs

How do I extract point data out of a browser-based map?

In particular, I need the park and ride points from http://wegenenverkeer.be/carpoolparkings, but I cannot find their WMS or shapefiles, anywhere. I can load the 'element' and see a script which loads the points, but don't know how to proceed with this code.

It can be WMS, WFS, anything I can load into my ArcMap file.

So the page gives the points in this script, can I use this in arcmap in some way?

```
{"projection":"EPSG:4326","attributes":{"name":"\u003Ch4\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022\/carpoolparkings\/oostkamp\u0022\u003EOostkamp\u003C\/a\u003E\u003C\/h4\u003E","description":"Afrit E40"},"wkt":"POINT (3.2319545170254 51.146994290477)"},{"projection":"EPSG:4326","attributes":{"name":"\u003Ch4\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022\/carpoolparkings\/oostkamp-2\u0022\u003EOostkamp 2\u003C\/a\u003E\u003C\/h4\u003E","description":"N50g \/ A10 (E40) - uitrit 9"},"wkt":"POINT (3.2474898713709 51.14465742022)"},
```

Comment: Have you tried contacting the site owners?  If so, what was their response?

Comment: No I haven't, will try tomorrow. Their WMS service only feature roads as they are a road agency and I cannot find this carpool/parkride anywhere else.

Comment: I would suggest scraping the data from the web map is not an appropriate use of the map. The spatial data is the intellectual property of someone, which you should respect by contacting the site as @PolyGeo suggested

Comment: The data you quote looks like GeoJSON to me - I've no idea if ArcMap can handle that but QGis can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requested data by agency, neatly received it by mail. Asked them to upload on their website for open data matters.